# Finding the ratio of sides knowing the ratio of angles in a triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Triangle ABC is such that its $3$ angles $A,B$ and $C$ are in the ratio $3:4:5$. What is the ratio of its $3$ sides $BC:CA:AB$?

I tried using the sine law but it was of no use, please give me help

Comment: For simplicity, scale the triangle so that one side has length 1. Then use the sine law.

Comment: @quasi how can i scale it if theyrre variables.. how can i sclae BC to 1????

Comment: this is what i did exactly:::::: Bc/Ca=3/4, BC/AB=3/5, CA/AB=4/5 however when i tried solving i got AB=AB ... etc

Comment: The angles hae the ratios 3:4:5, not the sides. Suppose the smallest angle is x. Then 3x + 4x + 5x = 180.

Comment: Since the given information only determines the angles, the triangle is determined only up to similarity, hence you can freely choose a value for one of the sides without changing the ratios of the sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:** The angles are $45, 60, 75$ degrees. The sine values for these angles are well-known, so you can answer your question using the Sine's Law.

---

We have $BC:CA:AB = \frac{BC}{AB} : \frac{CA}{AB} : 1 = \frac{\sin(A)}{\sin(C)} : \frac{\sin(B)}{\sin(C)} : 1$

Comment: wait.. how do u know the values of the angles???????????

Comment: @exchangehelpforuni: angles are $3k,4k,5k$ and the sum is $180°$

Comment: @exchangehelpforuni Let $A = x$. Then we have $B = \frac 43 A = \frac 43 x$. Similarly $C = \frac 53 x$. Then what is the sum of all angles in a triangle?

Comment: @stefan4024 thanks makes sense

Comment: @stefan4024 i used these angles and using the sine law i had 3 different equations with 3 different varibales, however the variables tend to cancel out leaving me with no answer, do u know what i should of

Comment: @exchangehelpforuni I'll add some further explanation in the answer.

Comment: @stefan4024 waittttttttttttt

Comment: @stefan204 i figured it out. i picked BC to have side length 1 and then calcuated CA: 3/sqrt6,   AB 1/sqrt3 -1... however now how can i determine the ratios, as im doing an online test which has mutliple choice asnwers

Comment: so do i just use the process of elimination

Comment: @exchangehelpforuni You can check the explanation I added.

Comment: @stefan4024 why is the thing i did wrong?? why should i insert he ratios from the beginig, why cant i just pick 1 to be a side

Comment: @exchangehelpforuni Actually you can do it. Then you will find an exact values for the rest two sides. In fact what I did was doing implicitly the very same thing. Pick $AB = 1$ and you will get the same.

Comment: @stefan4024 ok now what do i do next??

Comment: @exchangehelpforuni Then you have $BC = \frac{\sin(A)}{\sin(C)} \cdot AB = \frac{\sin(A)}{\sin(C)}$. Similarly $AC = \frac{\sin(B)}{\sin(C)} \cdot AB = \frac{\sin(B)}{\sin(C)}$

Comment: @stefan4024 these r the choices:                                                                A. 3^1/2 : 4^1/2 : 5^1/2
B.   (1 + 2^1/2) : 6^1/2 : (1 + 3^1/2)
C.   2 : 6^1/2 : (1 + 3^1/2)
D.   3 : 4 : 5
E.   6^1/2 : (1 + 3^1/2) : (2^1/2 + 3^1/2)

Comment: @Stefan4024 iknow i calucated and got all the values, however how can i match it and make it a ratio, similar to what the question is askingn ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52624/discussion-between-exchangehelpforuni-and-stefan4024).